# How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?

Tags: java, jar

I have created a [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_file) file. Now, I created another Java program. I want to unpack that JAR file in some other directory, meaning I want to do something like unzip.

If I run `jar -xf filename.jar` this causes some error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "jar": 
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
     at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:459)
     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:593)`
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Adapt this example: [How to extract Java resources from JAR and zip archive](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip49.html?page=1)

Or try this code:

> ## Extract the Contents of ZIP/JAR Files Programmatically
>
> Suppose `jarFile` is the jar/zip file to be extracted. `destDir` is the path where it will be extracted:
>
> ```
> java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(jarFile);
> java.util.Enumeration enumEntries = jar.entries();
> while (enumEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
>     java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enumEntries.nextElement();
>     java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
>     if (file.isDirectory()) { // if its a directory, create it
>         f.mkdir();
>         continue;
>     }
>     java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
>     java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
>     while (is.available() > 0) {  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
>         fos.write(is.read());
>     }
>     fos.close();
>     is.close();
> }
> jar.close();
> ```

**Source**: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/22124

Comment: Does this not work for anyone else?  I keep getting thrown FileNotFoundExceptions because of this.....

Comment: Same problem for me @Flafla2.

Comment: @lkjoel The reason that it's throwing an exception is because you're essentially trying to write stuff like "dest/folder1/file1" before you've created "dest/folder1".  To solve this, I recommend iterating through the JarEntry enumeration beforehand, and turning it into a list that is sorted on getName().size() (least to greatest).  That way, you'll create all necessary directories before getting to their child files/subdirectories.

Comment: have u tested this with a .zip file. cos a 'java.util.jar.JarFile' ref cannot refer to a zip file....this code may only work with jar files...

Comment: @frewper It seems that you could take a similar approach for Zip files using the `ZipFile` class.

Comment: @Destin Removing `f.mkdir()` and putting `f.getParentFile().mkdirs()` after the `if (file.isDirectory())` block worked perfectly for me, without sorting etc.

Comment: I wanted to add: unzipping this way gave me very poor unzip speed. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3321842/poor-performance-of-javas-unzip-utilities for alternatives.

Comment: To fix the exceptions, add "f.getParentFile().mkdirs();" directly after creating the new file.

Comment: After using it I am still getting FileNotFoundException. I am not sure what I am doing wrong but I am just providing jar name without specifying directory to that - cause I assume that JarFile should take jars from external libraries automatically , should ?

Comment: If you want to get Properties inside Jar this base code is good so thanks for that. I just removed the while loop and used jar.getEntry() to get the property file I needed and used the InputStream from that entry for Properties.load(). Note only for cases where the Jar is not in your class path. If it is in your class path use getResourceAsStream() from ResourceBundle instead.

Comment: This should be only used for jar files from trusted sources since it is vulnerable to the [zip-slip-vulnerability](https://github.com/snyk/zip-slip-vulnerability). (Though my edits pointing this out were rejected)

Comment: @Destin it's clever to compare it with sizes. Thanks.

Comment: what if we want to extract a several part inside that jar anyway? 1 or 2 files for instances....

Answer (score 12):

You can use this code snippet as a reference to get your task done.Its almost the same as the code snippet shown above by @JuanZe except that for those who were getting the FileNotFoundException, i have added a small code snippet that will check if the file does exist and if it doesn't then it will create the parent folder along with the files and will extract the contents of jar file inside the specified destination folder.

Code snippet:

```
public class JarDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
    java.util.jar.JarFile jarfile = new java.util.jar.JarFile(new java.io.File("E:/sqljdbc4.jar")); //jar file path(here sqljdbc4.jar)
    java.util.Enumeration<java.util.jar.JarEntry> enu= jarfile.entries();
    while(enu.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String destdir = "E:/abc/";     //abc is my destination directory
        java.util.jar.JarEntry je = enu.nextElement();

        System.out.println(je.getName());

        java.io.File fl = new java.io.File(destdir, je.getName());
        if(!fl.exists())
        {
            fl.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            fl = new java.io.File(destdir, je.getName());
        }
        if(je.isDirectory())
        {
            continue;
        }
        java.io.InputStream is = jarfile.getInputStream(je);
        java.io.FileOutputStream fo = new java.io.FileOutputStream(fl);
        while(is.available()>0)
        {
            fo.write(is.read());
        }
        fo.close();
        is.close();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: This code snipped will work for those who are getting FileNotFound Exception in previous case

Answer (score 5):

[JarFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) class.

```
JarFile file = new JarFile("file.jar");   
for (Enumeration<JarEntry> enum = file.entries(); enum.hasMoreElements();) {   
    JarEntry entry = enum.next();   
    System.out.println(entry.getName());   
}
```

Comment: Yes I want something like this but how can i store the extracted file in some other directory. Can you please guide me.

Comment: @gumuruh I've posted answer on Oct 7,2009 can you see that?

Answer (score 5):

Old question.
Here is a updated answer using :

- Java 7 `java.nio` to create and copy efficiently entries
- Java 8 `stream` to sort and collect the entries lexicographically (in order to always create folders first).

Note that I used `java.util.zip.ZipFile` (the base class) instead of `java.util.jar.JarFile` (the subclass).
The last one performs more things that are not required to "just" extract files from an archive.
So it reduces the overhead and prevents exception rising related to security concerns.  But if required you can of course replace `ZipFile/ZipEntry` by `JarFile/JarEntry`.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

public class FileUtils {

    public static void extractArchive(Path archiveFile, Path destPath) throws IOException {

        Files.createDirectories(destPath); // create dest path folder(s)

        try (ZipFile archive = new ZipFile(archiveFile.toFile())) {

            // sort entries by name to always create folders first
            List<? extends ZipEntry> entries = archive.stream()
                                                      .sorted(Comparator.comparing(ZipEntry::getName))
                                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

            // copy each entry in the dest path
            for (ZipEntry entry : entries) {
                Path entryDest = destPath.resolve(entry.getName());

                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    Files.createDirectory(entryDest);
                    continue;
                }

                Files.copy(archive.getInputStream(entry), entryDest);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I would do to extract my whole "resources" folder from my jar. It is way more faster to use BufferedReader and BufferedWriter.

```
 public static boolean extractResourcesToTempFolder() {
    try {
        //If folder exist, delete it.
        String destPath = getTempDir() + File.separator + "JToolkit" + File.separator;
        deleteDirectoryRecursive(new File(destPath));            

        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(JToolkit.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath());
        Enumeration<JarEntry> enums = jarFile.entries();
        while (enums.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry entry = enums.nextElement();
            if (entry.getName().startsWith("resources")) {
                File toWrite = new File(destPath + entry.getName());
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    toWrite.mkdirs();
                    continue;
                }
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(jarFile.getInputStream(entry));
                OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(toWrite));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                for (;;) {
                    int nBytes = in.read(buffer);
                    if (nBytes <= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                    out.write(buffer, 0, nBytes);
                }
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                in.close();
            }
            System.out.println(entry.getName());
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Methods.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Using Buffered reader, it gets done in seconds. Huge difference. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your title doesn't seem to match the question very well but if you really do want to "write [a] java program extracting a jar file" you just need [Class JarFile](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html).

Comment: yes i want to write a java program which will extract a jar file

Answer (score 1):

You can use this very simple library to **pack/unpack jar file**

[JarManager](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/src/367c0bcb2749/fr/stevecohen/jarmanager)

Very simple

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import fr.stevecohen.jarmanager.JarUnpacker;

class Test {
   JarUnpacker jarUnpacker = new JarUnpacker(); 
   File myfile = new File("./myfile.jar");
   File unpackDir = new File("./mydir");

   List<File> unpacked_files = jarUnpacker.unpack(myfile.getAbsolutePath(), unpackDir.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

You can also use **maven dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>fr.stevecohen.jarmanager</groupId>
    <artifactId>JarManager</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You also need my repository

```
<repository>
    <id>repo-reapersoon</id>
    <name>ReaperSoon's repo</name>
    <url>http://repo-maven.stevecohen.fr</url>
</repository>
```

Check the last version with the link bellow to use the last dependency

Please use my [public issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/ReaperSoon/maven-repo/issues) if you find some bugs

Answer (score 0):

Well here's my version, using `try-with-resources`:

```
    try (JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(artifact.getFile())) {
        for (JarEntry entry : Collections.list(jarFile.entries())) {
            try (InputStream is = jarFile.getInputStream(entry)) {
                File file = new File(targetDir, entry.getName());
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
                    fos.write(is.read());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new MyException(String.format(
            "Unable to open jar %s", artifact.getArtifactId()), e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested..

Here's a version for **Java 7+** using **buffered I/O** and **try-with-resources**.

```
public static void unzip(File archive, File destDir) throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256 * 1024];
    destDir.mkdirs();
    try (JarFile jar = new JarFile(archive)) {
        Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jar.entries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            JarEntry ent = entries.nextElement();
            File f = new File(destDir, ent.getName());
            if (ent.isDirectory()) {
                f.mkdir();
                continue;
            }
            try (InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(ent);
                 FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f)) {
                for (int r; (r = is.read(buffer)) > 0; ) {
                    os.write(buffer, 0, r);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, using **Java 8** and **org.apache.commons.io**
Its work for me.

```
File userDir = new File("resources");
userDir.mkdir();
JarFile jar = new JarFile("123.jar");
jar.stream()
   .filter(file -> 
    file.getName().contains("BOOT-INF/classes") && !file.getName().contains("BOOT-INF/classes/ch/"))
   .peek(file -> {
File res = new File(userDir.getPath() + file.getName().replaceAll("BOOT-INF/classes", ""));

     if (file.isDirectory()) {
          res.mkdirs();
     } else { try {
                  FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(jar.getInputStream(file), res);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
     }
     }).forEach(file -> LOGGER.info("Extract file: " + file.getName()));
```