# Java: create new files inside of running .jar

Tags: java, file, jar

I found and read this thread but I'm not sure if this answeres my question since I'm a beginner. Is there a way to do this which is not too complicated?
[How can my Java program store files inside of its .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056682/how-can-my-java-program-store-files-inside-of-its-jar-file)

So my program creates files outside of the .jar file while running:

```
wwbCopy = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("bstnCopy.xls"), wbook);
```

The Files are automatically created in the Folder where the .jar file is executed.

Comment: As mentioned in the answers to that question - don't do this - it's a really bad idea which won't work in many circumstances.

Comment: Lots of duplicates of this question (see https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20write%20to%20jar%20file).

Comment: Not to mention that in Java 9 (coming soon...ish) there will no longer be jar files. So this will be totally broken.

Comment: Thank you! I'm the worst googler ever..

Comment: That's an interesting thought.  Perhaps we should suggest to the StackOverflow that they create a "worst-googler-ever" badge.  To be awarded ... by acclamation :-)

Comment: Yeah that would be the award for me :D