# Extract directory from jar file

Tags: java

I have searched for this for a while now, but cant seem to figure it out. I want to extract a directory from a jar/zip file, and save it recursively to a path on the filesystem in java. Anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: Do you mean how to do this from within java code?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have been a bit more clear then the tag

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  What *specific* problems have you struck?

Comment: I have tried, and made success in extracting a file in itself, I want to extract one directory only from the jar.

Comment: I cant find a way to extract only that one directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1529611/429303) might give a good feeling how/where to start:

- [How to extract Java resources from JAR and zip archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-stores-its-data-in-spe/1529707#1529707)

Simply put, it's `java.util.jar` you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I know that the original question was actualy doing this programmatically.

But as it wasn't clear enough I guess many users (like me) ends up here when they just want to unzip a directory out of the jar using the jar command.

```
jar -xvf   <your>.jar  <required-dir>
```

E.g. extract META-INF directory out of some.jar

```
jar -xvf   some.jar  META-INF
```

to list the content of the jar use

```
jar -tvf   some.jar
```