# Extracting a file from the currently running JAR through code

Tags: java, file, jar, io, extract

Are there any built-in methods I can use to allow users to extract a file from the currently running JAR and save it on their disk?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`getResourceAsStream` (docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), you can do whatever you want with it after that.

For a two-liner you could use [one of the Commons IO copy methods](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#copyInputStreamToFile(java.io.InputStream,%20java.io.File)).

Comment: getResourceAsStream will give you access to any matching resource on the class path and not only a file withing the "currently running JAR", assuming that that is a JAR file executed with "java -jar <JAR-file>".

Comment: @jarnbjo Yep. And if the resource isn't properly packaged, that's *possibly* an issue, but given the question, I think the issue is much broader than needing it to come *specifically* from the "running jar", to the exclusion of all other resources packaged exactly the same.

Comment: Note that you may want to specify an *absolute* path to the file in the jar. And then *any* class can be used. Example: InputStream is = Object.class.getResource("/" + filename).openStream();

Answer (score 23):

```
File file = new File("newname.ext");
if (!file.exists()) {
     InputStream link = (getClass().getResourceAsStream("/path/resources/filename.ext"));
     Files.copy(link, file.getAbsoluteFile().toPath());
}
```

Comment: Note that some of Files.copy implementation (java.nio.file.Files) does not close the input stream -> possible memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether you will get know from which jar your class is getting executed but you can try this to extract resources from jar :
[How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s)