# Using JAR resource as File in java or scala

Tags: java, scala, jar, resources

I have developed an application that basically searches its `resources/runtime` directory, looking for `.java` files.

Having fetched all `.java` sources, it (together with program arguments) passes their absolute paths to [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html).

Of course, this approach doesn't work when application is deployed as a JAR package. So **the question** - how can I work with resource files as with regular files, i.e. pass their absolute path and read them afterwards?

I found some related topics here:

- [reading the file as a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144210/java-jar-file-use-resource-errors-uri-is-not-hierarchical)
- [making a resource copy to some temporary file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472408/extracting-a-file-from-the-currently-running-jar-through-code)

But what if I don't know names of the files? I seek solution that allows me to search the `resources/runtime` directory. Moreover, I think making a copy of file somewhere and delete it later on is clumsy solution.

I use combination of Java and Scala (with `sbt` build system), hence solution Java or Scala would be great.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say the "resources/runtime" directory? Do you mean a directory within the jar file, or a directory external to the jar file?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429172/how-do-i-list-the-files-inside-a-jar-file and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193786/how-to-use-classloader-getresources-correctly .