# How setProperty webdriver.chrome.driver,"\..\..\..\") in a jar but in unix environment?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

i'm doing a test with Selenium on my PC with windows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "src\\test\\java\\resources\\chromedriver.exe");
```

it work correctly if i run test inside project with eclipse.
But when i package into jar my project include also test\java\resources\chromedriver.exe and put this jar and load jar in my project it dont load driver:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847) ~[na:na]
etc....
```

How i must set path in project Selenium for load driver?

UPDATE:
i must test it on Unix Machine
Thanks
Regards

Answer (score -1):

You can e.g. extract the `chromedriver.exe` or `chromedriver` (depending on the host OS) from your `JAR` on runtime and then pass the extracted `chromedriver`'s file path via

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "...");
```

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472408) question.