# Run a R script from a java jar

Tags: java, jar, external-process

I have a java program that calls a R script.
Here is the command:

```
String filename = "hierarchicalClusteringScript.R";
String[] cmd=new String[]{this.conn.getRPath(),"CMD","BATCH",
            "--args LD_matrix='"+LD_matrix+"' " +
            "image_filename='"+image_filename+"' " +
            "width="+300+" "+
            "height="+height+" "+
            "ordered_snps_filename='"+ordered_snps_filename+"'",
            filename,
               this.conn.getWorkingDir()+this.conn.getProjectName()+"Routput.txt"};
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process process = runtime.exec(cmd);
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I would like to include the R script "hierarchicalClusteringScript.R" into the jar file. In case I do is there a way to call the script from code? Which path should I use?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Is 'R' capable to executing a script from a compressed file?

Comment: I don't know...I was wondering if that was possible or if I need to put the file in another place

Comment: Well, I'd suggest that you probably going to run into problems, how ever, you extract the script from the Jar file @ runtime to temp location and execute from there

Comment: Can you point me to the command I need to use to do that in Java? Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extract the script from your JAR, normally we seldom perform a JAR/ZIP extract.  When you put the script in the JAR, it usually implies that it is in your classpath.  Therefore, just locate it as a resource, get the inputStream to it, and read the resources and write it to a temp directory.  These few steps should be easy enough that you can easily find code sample from the net easily.

some hints for you:

```
Class#getResourceAsStream()
FileOutputStream
File#createTempFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

Jar files are essentially Zip files (with a Manifest).

You can extract files out of these using the [Jar API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/package-summary.html)

Essentially, you want to open the `JarFile`, find the `JarEntry` and using the `JarOutputStream` extract the contents

You can have a look at [How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s) for an example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are looking to add R script to jar and load R as a resource from jar classpath.
(jar can contain any types of files, but JVM can only run what is bytecode compatible)

-- To add script to existing jar do this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

-- To create new jar with script do this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

-- To load the script from jar make sure it is in a classpath and in your code load it with ResourceLoader:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html