# Building file.jar, External Executable File missing

Tags: java, file, jar, external, executable

Assuming that I use NetBeans 7.3 , I created a project that, in a nutshell, receiving as input a set of parameters, it returns as output a print on screen. The project is made up of a number of directories. Each directory contains a class (in file.class form). One of these directory contains an executable in C. I wrote it as the kernel of the Java project.

I built file.jar and I added it as a library in a new project. When I tried to test it, an error message made ​​me realize that the C written program is not was automatically added to file.jar under construction.

One of my first attempt to solve this problem was to manually add the C-executable file. By using the JAR command from the terminal on my Mac, I was able to update the file.jar adding the executable in the right subfolder.

This solution is not served because, moving from project to file.jar, the relative path that leads to the execution of the C-program has changed. So I tried to change this path seeing it from the point of view of file.jar. Yet this attempt was futile.

I defer to those with more experience than me in the packaging and distribution of Java content.

Comment: What does the c program do, is it really needed?

Comment: Yes, it is needed. I cannot remove it. Because it is the kernel of Java Project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an operating system cannot directly execute an executable that is inside a zip file (which is what a jar file actually is). It has to be first extracted.

So your program could first [open its own jar file and extract the executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s) into a file on disk, then run that file.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an installer program, to install both the jar file and the executable file to a suitable location on the user's disk.

Comment: Mmm ... I understand what you said. So, if I wanted to take this project and create an executable how should I do? (Have you ever built a C project into an executable? Thou knowest that all project files become one file that may be booted from the terminal, like Mac Terminal for example)

Comment: that is a new question, please ask a new question. actually please don't, because it is probably a duplicate.

Comment: Strange... ok, i create new question.