# How do I execute a java executable (jar) by code in java?

Tags: java, file

How I can execute a jar file via java code?

I want to execute a java executable called "Console.jar" by code but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Open it for what purpose? A jar is more or less just a zip file. Use a zip utility.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a Java program which can extract a JAR file and store its data in specified directory (location)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s)

Comment: @Pillar I want to open the file with Java. I don't want to extract it

Comment: Then use Java's zip utility. But, again, what are you planning to do with the contents?

Comment: The jar file is a my creation file, and I want to open it with an another jar file @Pillar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pro way to do it [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html):

```
//Create a process builder
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar","path/f.jar", "argument 1","argument 2");

//start it
Process process = builder.start();
```

So you can have control over the jar you have already opened.You can get it's output,close it,be notified if it crashed etc.

Answer (score 2):

A jar is simply a zip with a different extension.

So if you like to see what is present inside a jar simply rename it to .zip and open with your preferred zip client (winzip, winrar, unzip, 7zip...)

---

If you need to launch an executable jar from command line:

```
java -jar <jarFileWithJarExtension>
```

for example

```
java -jar Console.jar
```

---

If you need to launch it from a java application you can do that with the following code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar Console.jar");
```

If you need also to interact with Console.jar take a look at the class [`Process`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)

Comment: Did you miss "with java" ?

Comment: There's no need to rename it.

Comment: @Pillar you can also open it without renaming but for most of people is simpler to rename it and open it with a double click than opening it with the standard File - Open (or similar) function of the zip client

Comment: No, I don't want to extract the jar file, but open it with Java

Comment: @Frank what do you mean for "open" ? Launch an executable jar? Use the jar as a library in a java project? Open from java as a file and read the bytes?

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO launch an executable jar with a code